# Excel file gets crashed while Appending record to it

Tags: java, excel

I am using this code to append a record to an excel file, but this code crashes the existing file instead of appending record to it. So please tell how can I append a record to my excel file?

**Code:**

```
public static void writeToExcel() {

        try {
            File file = new File("C:\\Users\\abc\\Desktop\\Selenium Tests.xlsx");
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file,true);
            XSSFWorkbook  workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();            
            XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("fund");  
            int rowNum = sheet.getLastRowNum()+1;
            Row row = sheet.createRow(rowNum);   
            Cell cell0 = row.createCell(0);
            cell0.setCellValue("Nav Value 1");
            Cell cell1 = row.createCell(1);
            cell1.setCellValue("Amount Change 1");       
            Cell cell2 = row.createCell(2);
            cell2.setCellValue("Percent Change 1");
            workbook.write(fos);
            fos.flush();
            fos.close();
            System.out.println("done");
        }
        catch (Exception exp) {
            exp.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have open the workbook with an InputStream

> InputStream fos = new FileInputStream(fileName);

and use a FileOutputStream to write file.

> FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(fileName);
>   workbook.write(fileOut);

There is no need to add 1 to the last row number.

> int rowNum = sheet.getLastRowNum() + 1;

The cells are 0 based

> Cell cell0 = row.createCell(0);

```
public static void writeToExcel() {

    try {

        try {
            String fileName = "C:\\Users\\best buy\\Downloads\\_temp.xlsx";
            InputStream fos = new FileInputStream(fileName);
            Workbook workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(fos);
            Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheet("fund");  
            int rowNum = sheet.getLastRowNum()+1;
            Row row = sheet.createRow(rowNum);   
            Cell cell0 = row.createCell(0);
            cell0.setCellValue("Nav Value 1");
            Cell cell1 = row.createCell(1);
            cell1.setCellValue("Amount Change 1");      
            Cell cell2 = row.createCell(2);
            cell2.setCellValue("Percent Change 1");
            // Write the output to a file
            FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(fileName);
            workbook.write(fileOut);
            fileOut.close();

            System.out.println("done");
        }
        catch (Exception exp) {
            exp.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception exp) {
        exp.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```